# wordpress blog in android

Tags: android

I want to make an application in android where i want to pull the Blog of the site (http://dekora.com/blog/) which is in wordpress.
But i don't have any idea how to pull the blogs from wordpress, is there any api or source code available. i have gone through wordpress website and tried to understand the api of Android but dint get it well.
So i am just wondering to find some proper clue. Can any body help what approach should i take
to pull the blogs from wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the RSS-Feed? Its a standard-api an there is ton of information about this. The URL of the feed is `http://dekora.com/blog/?feed=rss2` and IBM got a nice tutorial on parsing and using RSS on its [homepage](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html)

Comment: gr8.. thanks for your help.. now its clear.. hope now i will be able to  do the rest of the thing..

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress-Java library can be useful for you :

[wordpress-java](http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-java/)

Let us know if you try and successfully use it.